# Finding a cycle from an ordered list

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, computer-science

Given a random list of all square matrix elements e.g. $\{A_{1,3},A_{2,5},A_{2,1},A_{3,2}, \dots\}$

I want to be able to find the first 3-cycle $\{A_{a,b},A_{b,c},A_{c,a}\}$ in this list.

This is the same as constructing a graph edge by edge and asking for the edges of the first triangle to appear. What is an efficient way to find the triangle?

Thanks in advance. Ben

Comment: Does that mean you effectively have a list of _pairs_, or do you need to look up elements in a matrix (where they could be appearing zero or multiple times)?

Comment: Effectively a list of pairs. The elements of the matrix are just numbers. I have ordered the elements from largest to smallest. - this is where the list came from. I'm looking for the largest 3 numbers to form a cycle.

Comment: Are your pairs ordered? If so, do you need the three pairs that make up your triangle to have appeared in exactly the order you have listed them in here?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, the list itself is ordered, but the cycle need not be. Once a permutation of 3 elements forms a cycle, that's sufficient for me.

Comment: In the example above $\{A_{1,3}, A_{2,1}, A_{3,2} \}$ would be a valid cycle.

Comment: How about $A_{1,2},A_{1,3},A_{2,3}$?

Comment: Why not just a BFS? There is an adjacency matrix version

Comment: @ΜάρκοςΚαραμέρης  I don't know/recall what that is.